# How to display itemCount using the Shortlist plugin?

Tags: plugin-shortlist

I am using the [Shortlist](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/shortlist) plugin as a rating system throughout the site and need to display the numeral for the total, with a very simple conditional.

```
{% set item = craft.shortlist.item('favourites') %}

{% if craft.shortlist.itemCount > 0 %}
    **{{ number }}**<i class="fa fa-large fa-heartbeat">
{% else %}
    <i class="fa fa-large fa-heart-o">
{% endif %}
```

I have tried `{{ item }}`, `{{ count }}`, `{{ itemCount }}`, but am unable to display a numeral.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Never used the plugin before, but it looks like `itemCount` is the thing to use, but it was added in v1.1. Are you running that version? https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/shortlist/usage/variables

Comment: Thanks Brad, yes I am running v1.1.0 and {{ itemCount }} triggers; "Variable "itemCount" does not exist".

Comment: Oh... looks like it's `craft.shortlist.itemCount` https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/shortlist/usage/variables#itemCount

Comment: Brilliant Brad, still getting used to reading/understanding the Craft lingo..

Comment: Awesome... will go ahead and add that as an official answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/shortlist/usage/variables#itemCount) is looks like the correct syntax to use is:

```
{{ craft.shortlist.itemCount }}
```